# Need help editing sumif macro to automatically update and go to next row

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I have tried recording a macro that will update a sumifs formula based on two criteria, and i would like for it to move onto the next row and past the sumifs with it updating for that row.It may be helpful to note the criteria range and sum range are being pulled from a separate excel file.I cannot seem to get my code to work for more than one row. Here is my code:

```
 Sub Sumifmacro()
    '
    ' Sumifmacro Macro
    '
    '
    Range("N154").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIFS('[CPI Project Cost Update.xlsx]PROJECT COSTING'!C24, '[CPI 
    Project Cost Update.xlsx]PROJECT COSTING'!C1, ""February"", '[CPI 
    Project Cost Update.xlsx]PROJECT COSTING'!C12, ""5395b"")"
    Range("N155").Select
    End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need VBA for this, you could use a data table to update the formula with each new row. How were you expecting to trigger the macro ?

Type the formula manually, recorder is messing with your ranges.

When working on multiple spreadsheet, naming the ranges might come in handy.

Be aware that your values will not update if "CPI Project Cost Update.xlsx" is closed as you are using a SUMIFS.